# Instead of deleting the rows one by one in excel, the whole data is getting deleted in one execution of loop

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

Instead of deleting every row one by one,its deleting all the data of the excel sheet in one execution. The problem is that i dont want to delete the columns and hence i am iterating the loop till 2. But while debugging i found that in one execution of the loop,that is, i=47 that is the last row , its deleting all the records.

//last row=47

```
for (int i = lastRow; i >= 2; i--)
            {
                Array MyValues = (Array)MySheet.get_Range("A" + i.ToString(), "L" + i.ToString()).Cells.Value;//storing the range of values in an array
                if (Convert.ToString(MyValues.GetValue(1,1))=="" && Convert.ToString(MyValues.GetValue(1,2))==""&&Convert.ToString(MyValues.GetValue(1,3))=="")
                {
                    break;
                }

                else
                {
                    Excel.Range cells = MySheet.get_Range("A" + i.ToString(), "L" + i.ToString());
                    cells.Delete();
                }
            }
```

Comment: Please be clearer on your end goal. Your loop starts from the row 47 of the excel spread sheet. You break out of the loop only when cells A through C are equal "" otherwise, you delete the cells A# through L#. Do you have any A through C combination in your document that are all equal ""? So.. unless that's the case, rows 47 to 2 will have the cells deleted.

Comment: The problem is that all the rows are getting deleted even the columns in one execution that is at the first execution only. Its very weird.

Comment: Put a break after the else so it runs only once and check the result. Try it with [...]get_Range("A$" + i.ToString [...]

Comment: already tried not working...after first execution, the spreadsheet is empty and in the second execution it is doing break and hence coming out of the loop